# How to prevent illegal ICloneable<T> inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, inheritance-prevention

I have an interface :

```
public interface ICloneable<out T>
    where T : ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}
```

that should receive a type that implement this interface (as shown below).
And I can create a class that implement it :

```
public class Class : ICloneable<Class>
{
    public Class Clone() { return (Class)MemberwiseClone(); }
}
```

Great !

But anyone can create a class that implement ICloneable<T> "wrong".
**Does exist a way to prevent inheritance as shown below ?** (2 examples)

```
public class Other : ICloneable<Class>
{
    public Class Clone() { return new Class(); }
}
```

```
public class Other : Class, ICloneable<Class>
{
    public Class Clone() { return (Other)MemberwiseClone(); }
}
```

And allow inheritance as shown below ? (any from 2 examples)

```
public class Other : ICloneable<Other>
{
    public Other Clone() { return (Other)MemberwiseClone(); }
}
```

```
public class Other : Class, ICloneable<Other>
{
    public Other Clone() { return (Other)MemberwiseClone(); }
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed)?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: @John Wu, no, I don't want to make classes as sealed (in common case).

@mjwills, I want to prevent this :
`ICloneable<Class>[] array = new[] { new Class(), new Other() };`

Comment: @leofun01That doesn't answer _why_. That answers _what_.

Comment: So you're asking if it's possible for any class to implement an interface using only itself as a parameter? So `class Foo : ICloneable<Bar>` wouldn't work, it *has* to be `class Foo : ICloneable<Foo>`?

Comment: @AustinWBryan, yes, Exactly!

Comment: And do you plan on having more than one of these classes, like a `Foo : ICloneable<Foo>`, `Bar : ICloneable<Bar>`, etc?

Comment: @AustinWBryan, yes. I have many cloneable classes in my project.

Comment: @leofun01 - The language does not support this. You just have to be careful when implementing your classes.

Comment: @Enigmativity, yeah, it looks like.

Comment: Since your `Class`, `Other` classes and `ICloneable` interface are public, then any developer can use it however he wants. You can tell user what your classes should do (describe interface), but you can't tell them how to implement it. Moreover, I personally still don't see any possible applicability of this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot overload a class, so:

```
public class Other : Class {}
public class Other : Class, IC<Other> {}
```

Will never work.

Now, I'm gonna pull a Jon Skeet and show how you *could* do this, but then discourage you from doing it. You could do something like this:

```
public class CloneableOther : Class, ICloneable<Other> {  }
public class Other : CloneableOther
{

}    

public class CloneableFoo : Class, ICloneable<Foo> { }
public class Foo : CloneableFoo
{

}
```

What this code is doing is effectively removing the generic parameter from the inheritance. Except, `Foo` can still do this: `Foo : CloneableFoo, ICloneable<Other>`, and now you'll have to create two classes for every `ICloneable` instance.

This goes into that *why* do you need this in the first place? It is a practice to do `Foo : IInterface<Foo>`, but there's no way to enforce it. Your best bet is to just do copy and paste and just be sure that the class matches.

Maybe another way is to have in the constructor of `Class`, a check to see if the type of `ICloneable` is the type of the class, and to throw an exception if it isn't, and that could sort've feel like a compile time error, if it's done earlier enough in the runtime.

Comment: Because the point is to pass in a type parameter, but he's wanting to remove it all together, but I could be wrong in that

Comment: I don't think he wants to remove it completely. He wants to enforce the right one.

Comment: I realized, which is why I removed that bit. It's weird, I feel like there should be a way to do that.

Comment: You can't subclass a `public class Other` from a `private class`... You get an error. See for example [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACgiAHBASwDcJ4sAmDAYQBsB7AOzgmGbgHkYAC0QYA3hgC+RFAGZ6GAcIQYQTNp269FiIqKJTCQA=)

Comment: @xanatos Thanks, forgot that. I figured it would be better for encapsulation.